# Why is Visual Studio 2010's solution explorer so friggin' jumpy?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

I am getting the following error on when I try to compile:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(269,9):
>   error MC6000: Project file must
>   include the .NET Framework assembly
>   'WindowsBase, PresentationCore,
>   PresentationFramework' in the
>   reference list.

This project is the Web backend for a Silverlight Business Application with very little modification.  When I do add these references, everything breaks.  I've tried removing every single reference from my references until all I had left was a reference to System.  I still get the error though.  In fact it is the only error that shows up.

**Edit**

Figured it out, and I have a new question:  I accidentally moved (dragged) a XAML file from my Silverlight front-end project. Visual Studio is very finicky and will drag something at the drop of a hat. When I click an item, even if I release the mouse right away, sometimes it will drag the item following the mouse.   Is there a way to make it less jumpy?

Comment: DO you have the Silverlight Toolkit installed?

Comment: @Jeff, I do.  This was compiling before.

Answer (score 5):

If you copied or moved an item from another project, its "Build Action" property might be set to "Page". This happened to me, and changing it to "Resource" (because that's what the item was) fixed the problem.

I've copied this answer from another site. It was the problem I was facing.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/7bf38ed6-43f8-492e-a304-0842e6c7c6b2/

Comment: Ditto.  Fixed me up.  Thanks!